# Allow Multiple Cross Origin in Spring Boot back end /Angularjs Front End application?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, configuration

I am receiving the following error in the web application I am currently working for  here is the ErrorCode:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://rev-final.staging.cashu.com:8080/merchants/signup. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

so what can I do to solve such a problem and the solution must be from angular side or Spring Side because I am finding configuration on both while I am searching for a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the below class in your component scan package then everything will be taken care by spring.Please refer [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) for further reference..

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

public SimpleCORSFilter() {
log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```